# Bitcoin RPC. How to close wallet files opened by bitcoin?

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc

Bitcoin RPC unloadwallet command does not close files opened by bitcoind process.
I want to generate addresses for multiple wallets (over 1000) and get 'Too many opened files error'.
Is there a way to close files, associated with unloaded wallet?

.bitcoin/testnet3/wallets/3f7b93e26b498be43235a9beda796d8d/.walletlock
.bitcoin/testnet3/wallets/3f7b93e26b498be43235a9beda796d8d/db.log
.bitcoin/testnet3/wallets/3f7b93e26b498be43235a9beda796d8d/database/log.0000000001

Comment: To begin with, why on earth do you want to do that?

Comment: For my project. I generate wallets for customers

Comment: That’s generally not how people go about this. At the very least the software isn’t designed to handle tens or hundreds of wallets. Generally speaking if you’re handling customer money it’ll just end up all in one wallet.

Comment: Thank you for comments. But why money would end up in one wallet? I have multiple folders under wallets directory. And Bitcoin RPC allows to create and switch between wallets

Comment: Why would you want them in separate wallets?

Comment: To separate users funds safely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/15291#issuecomment-459131886) and has been fixed for 0.18 which will be released in the coming weeks.

Comment: Yes, thank you a lot. Already found that 
Soooo glad it is fixed :) I'm the happiest person today!